# Laminas Authentication adapter is being overwritten

Tags: laminas

I'm running into an issue where Laminas's Authentication Service's adapter is being overwritten from another module. How I have it set up is that under the Application module it sets the adapter, which is fine, but when I have it set the Adapter under another module, it overwrites the adapter in Application, or so I think that this is the issue, because when I prevent the other module from being initialized, it works just fine.

Here is the code I have in place for Module.php in the Application Module:

```
 AuthenticationService::class => function($container) {
     $db_adapter = $container->get(Adapter::class);
     $auth_adapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($db_adapter, 'users', 'username', 'password');

     $auth_service = new AuthenticationService();
     $auth_service->setAdapter($auth_adapter);
     $auth_service->setStorage($container->get(LoginAuthStorage::class));
                
     return $auth_service;
 },
```

And here is the code in the other module

```
  AuthenticationService::class => function($container) {
      $db_adapter = $container->get(Adapter::class);
      $auth_adapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($db_adapter, 'admins', 'username', 'password');

      $auth_service = new AuthenticationService();
      $auth_service->setAdapter($auth_adapter);
      $auth_service->setStorage($container->get(AdminLoginAuthStorage::class));

      return $auth_service;
 },
```

For further clarification, here is the list of module namespaces being loaded:

```
    /**
 * List of enabled modules for this application.
 *
 * This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
 */
return [
    'Laminas\Navigation',
    'Laminas\Mail',
    'Laminas\Di',
    'Laminas\Log',
    'Laminas\Db',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\FilePrg',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\FlashMessenger',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\Identity',
    'Laminas\Mvc\Plugin\Prg',
    'Laminas\Session',
    'Laminas\Mvc\I18n',
    'Laminas\Form',
    'Laminas\Hydrator',
    'Laminas\InputFilter',
    'Laminas\Filter',
    'Laminas\I18n',
    'Laminas\Router',
    'Laminas\Validator',
    'Laminas\Diactoros',
    'Application',
    'Admin',
];
```

If I comment out 'Admin', it works fine but if not, it tries to fetch the adapter I defined for the admin module under application.

I apologize in advance if my question is unclear, I am uncertain how to phrase it to be honest. What I am basically am trying to do is to have one authentication service for users under the application module and an authentication service for admins under the admin module.

Thanks!

Comment: So, basically, you what to use two different storages depending on the user type (normal/admin)? Or you have two separated login pages, one for users and one for admins?

Comment: yes but the adapter keeps getting overwritten. I have two modules that are separated but for some reason it overwrites the one in user

Comment: Yes, I understood that you have two different modules, but, do you have only ONE login page, or you have two separate pages? If you only have one login form, it is quite obvious that you can't have two different authentication service, because there could only be one `AuthenticationService` declaration in your configuration. It is not possible to have two different objects under the same "key".

Comment: Moreover, even if you were using two different FQDN, with only one page it would be impossible for the server to instantiate the correct `AuthenticationService`, because at that moment it is unknown if the user which must be authenticated is an "user" or an "admin"

Comment: I don't understand why you would store authentication under two different storage (because you'd also need to know from which storage to read), but I suggest you to take a look to the [ChainStorage](https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-authentication/storage/#chain-storage)